sh spawn expect - handling multiple lines in expect command
I am encrypting source files using PGP encryption. After importing the key, every time I run the script it is expecting a confirmation. But in Production I am planning to use spawn and expect commands, the problem here is, the PGP encryption command is prompting a multi line with special characters text. I tried copying that text and pass in expect command. Tried options of regular expressions etc, but no luck. Any suggestions if anyone has overcome this problem? Thanks for your suggestions.
Here is my shell script.
\usr\bin\expect -d <<-!EXP >> /logname 2>&1 

spawn /ur/bin/gpg --encrypt -r <publickey> <filename> >> logname 2>&1 sleep 1 

expect " 

Pub <key> IT security (contact us at email <its@abc.com>
Primary Key fingerprint: 339D O998
Subkey fingerprint: F779 D999 

It is not certain that the key belongs to the person named
in the user ID. If you *really* know what you are doing, 
you may answer the next question with yes.

Use this key anyway? (y/N)"
sleep 1
send "y\r"
expect eof
!EXP

The problem is with the expect text. When I run the PGP manually, I am getting this text prompt. So had to copy the same text in expect command and send the response as 'y'.

Thanks, @CharlesDuffy. I have added the code to my original question.

I'd also skip the shell wrapper and just make it an expect script -- start with #!/usr/bin/env expect -f and then you don't need any heredoc to wrap the expect code, since the entire file is expect code. (That simplifies things because a heredoc with an unquoted sigil has shell expansions within its text run before being written to disk; it doesn't look to me like you actually intend those expansions to take place).

Considered setting up the trust database to mark the key trusted so it doesn't prompt for it in the first place? In a past life, setting something like this up, I distributed a GNUPGHOME directory (equivalent to ~/.gnupg) alongside my code and set environment variables to use it during execution; that way you can have which keys to trust pre-configured alongside the keyring itself. (Mind, more recently I stopped using gnupg altogether and use Go's x/crypto/openpgp library instead)

you dont have to expect the whole multi line message. you can just expect "Use this key anyway? (y/N)".

@sexpect Indeed, but there's value to failing unless we see the signature of the specific expected key, which is what I assume the OP was going for here.

thanks for all the responses. I had an alternate approach for not prompting the confirmation dialogue. By using "--trust-model always" to the GPG command,  which will not ask if the key is from trusted source.
